# Ordering Feature Attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, feature-class, personal-geodatabase

I have a polygon feature layer I am updating within a personal geodatabase. I have ordered my attributes in the table in a certain way for data entry. Every time I re-open the feature for editing, I have to re-order the fields to my preferred order. Could someone help me figure out how to make my preference the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Save an MXD with that layer in it with the fields sorted the way you want them.  Every time you go to make an edit open that MXD.
2. Set the fields the way you want them and then create a layer file using the 'Save as Layer File...' option when you right-click on the layer.  Then pull this layer file into any open MXD to do your edits.

You can't change the order permanently directly to the geodatabase : http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004981

Comment: Thank you Brian, I banged my head on the keyboard once I figured out how simple this was. I must have forgotten to save changes during my last session of the MXD. I did not know about exporting a layer file as a way to also retain edits. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Brian's answer above](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/210938/64785), there is also a third option:

3. Recreate your feature class with the fields in the order you want them.  Depending on the number of attributes you probably have two ways you could do this:

   1. Create a new feature class, add the fields in the order you want and copy/paste your existing features into the new feature class (if the fields all have identical names between the two feature classes everything will copy across)
   2. If only a few fields, you could use the [Alter Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/alter-field-properties.htm) tool to rename your existing fields, create new fields in your desired order, and [Calculate Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm) your attributes across, then delete your old renamed fields.

My recommendation would be to create a new feature class anyway, as if something goes wrong you still have your original.

If you have X-Tools Pro, there is an option in [Table Restructure](https://xtools.pro/en/features/table-operations/table-restructure/) to reorder fields - I believe this reorders them and saves to a new feature class, so automates #1 above.

Comment: Thank you for the input. All the ideas you suggested are methods I would consider. They are much appreciated.